# Why would a user set a bounty and only accept the answer after the bounty is over?

Tags: support, bounties, accepted-answer

This just happened to me in this question:

[How to create a rule for a contact group/distribution list in order to move emails to a certain folder for Outlook 2013?](https://superuser.com/questions/664128/how-to-create-a-rule-for-a-contact-group-distribution-list-in-order-to-move-emai/)

I gave the user two acceptable answers but he only accepted it 3 hours after the bounty was over.

What does the grace period means?

Comment: The grace period means there is still time to award the bounty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People don't always watch their bounty and miss the deadline.

So we added a grace period after the bounty has come to an end so they can go and award it when they get the notification/email that is is finished.

Comment: I added a bounty for the express purpose of rewarding an existing answer, and still needed the reminder email to actually award it. People are people.